# How can I execute the MSSQL query without error?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to execute mssql query but its showing error.The same query I executed in MySQL its working fine.

The Query is:

```
SELECT tst_flow_name, tst_flow_desc,COUNT(tst_flow) tot 
FROM test_flow_details  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tst_flow ON tst_flow_name=tst_flow 
                        AND test_flow_details.project=tst_flow.project 
WHERE  test_flow_details.project='JupiterQA'
```

ERROR IS:

> Column 'test_flow_details.tst_flow_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How can I execute the MSSQL query without error.

Comment: Q : How can I execute the MSSQL query without error? A : Have your code fixed ;p

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix normal column selects with aggregate function call like `count()`.

Group by the columns you want to be unique and then you can add `count()`

```
SELECT tst_flow_name, tst_flow_desc, COUNT(*) tot 
FROM test_flow_details  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tst_flow ON tst_flow_name=tst_flow 
                        AND test_flow_details.project=tst_flow.project 
WHERE  test_flow_details.project='JupiterQA'
GROUP BY tst_flow_name, tst_flow_desc
```